# Crawling through Web-pages that have categories

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap a website that has a uncommon web-page structure, page upon page upon page until i get to the item i'm trying to extract data from,

edit(Thanks to the answers, I have been able to extract most data I require, however I need the path links to get to the said product)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'drapertools.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.drapertools.com/category/0/Product%20Range']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/category-?.*?/'])),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/product/']), callback='parse_product'),
    )

    def parse_product(self, response):

        yield {
            'product_name': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-title"]//h1[@class="text-primary"]/text()').extract_first(),
            'product_number': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-title"]//h1[@style="margin-bottom: 20px; color:#000000; font-size: 23px;"]/text()').extract_first(),
            'product_price': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-title"]//p/text()').extract_first(),
            'product_desc': response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left"]//div[@class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11"]//p/text()').extract_first(),
            'product_path': response.xpath('//div[@class="nav-container"]//ol[@class="breadcrumb"]//li//a/text()').extract(),
            'product_path_links': response.xpath('//div[@class="nav-container"]//ol[@class="breadcrumb"]//li//a/href()').extract(),
        }
```

I don't know if this would work or anything, can anyone please help me here?
I would greatly appreciate it.

More Info:
I'm trying to access all categories and all items within them
however there is a categories within them and even more before I can get to the item.

I'm thinking of using Guillaume's LinkExtractor Code but i'm not sure that is supposed to be used for the outcome I want...

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/category-?.*?/'])),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/product/']), callback='parse_product'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead! It's perfect for this use-case!

It basically gets all the links for every page recursively, and calls a callback only for the interesting ones (I'm assuming that you are interested in the products).

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'drapertools.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.drapertools.com/category/0/Product%20Range']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/category-?.*?/'])),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/product/']), callback='parse_product'),
    )

    def parse_product(self, response):

        yield {
            'product_name': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-title"]//h1[@class="text-primary"]/text()').extract_first(),
        }
```

Comment: I am Interested in getting the product details just to be clear, I'm trying to extract their titles, stock/part number, price and specifications.
+ sorry for late reply

Comment: I want to thank Guillaume for the code, it really helped me make progress however, we need the path links in form of a string (look at product_path_links)
+Code above has been updated

Answer (score 0):

You have the same structure for all pages, maybe you can shorten it?

```
import scrapy

class DraperToolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'drapertools_spider'
    start_urls = ["https://www.drapertools.com/category/0/Product%20Range"]


    def parse(self, response):
        # this will call self.parse by default for all your categories
        for url in response.css('.category p a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url))  

        # here you can add some "if" if you want to catch details only on certain pages
        for req in self.parse_details(response):
            yield req

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {}
```

Comment: I can kinda see what your doing here, however could you give a more detailed explanation? Like, how would I be able to get the next set of URLs for the categories inside, and then the items within them?

Comment: I've updated css selector according to your website. It is just a recursion, that gets us to the deepest category and also we can scrape details that you need from all the pages. Or, you can add "if" statement to catch it only on some concrete categories.